# How to pass data from First TabBarItem to Second TabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

[image]

Above I have a `TabBarController` with 4 buttons. When I press the second `TabBarItem`(Cars) **or** third `TabBarItem`(Bicycles) I want to pass some values from the first`TabBarItem`(HomeScreen) .
I'm using Swift 5 and I don't have a `SceneDelegate` in my main project (is a 3 years old project), I have only the `AppDelegate` and this is why I wasn't able to try the only example which I found from Stackoverflow about a similar question like mine.
I managed somehow to pass the data between `ViewControllers` through `TabBarController` but I don't think is the right approach anymore (as some people from this community are also saying this on some threads) because when I click on different `TabBarItems` the data get lost and after is showing up again but with the wrong values etc.
I will attach below a GIF with the bugs which I'm getting while I navigate and also my current code with a link to the DEMO project on GitHub (https://github.com/florentin89/PassDataTabBarController/)

Can you help me please to pass the data using the right implementation ?

Here is my code for HomeScreen `ViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var textfieldHoldingCarsValue: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textfieldHoldingBicyclesValue: UITextField!
    
    var valueForCarsScreen = String()
    var valueForBicyclesScreen = String()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        valueForCarsScreen = textfieldHoldingCarsValue.text ?? String()
        valueForBicyclesScreen = textfieldHoldingBicyclesValue.text ?? String()
        
        if let navController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? UINavigationController{
            if let carsTab = navController.children.first as? PostcodeViewController{
                carsTab.receivedValueFromHomeScreen = valueForCarsScreen
            }
        }
        
        if let navController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[2] as? UINavigationController{
            if let bicyclesTab = navController.children.first as? PostcodeViewController{
                bicyclesTab.receivedValueFromHomeScreen = valueForBicyclesScreen
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Logout the user and navigate to Login screen
    @IBAction func logoutTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the `ViewController` used for second and third `TabBarItem`:

```
import UIKit

class PostcodeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var receivedValueLabel: UILabel!
    
    var receivedValueFromHomeScreen = String()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        if self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex == 1 {
            receivedValueLabel.text = "Value received for Cars: \n" + receivedValueFromHomeScreen
        }

        if self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex == 2 {
            receivedValueLabel.text = "Value received for Bicycles: \n" + receivedValueFromHomeScreen
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a GIF with the bugs/glitches which I'm getting when I navigate between `ViewControllers`:

[image]

Thank you for reading this !

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that viewWillAppear of PostcodeViewController is called before the selectedIndex of your tabbar is changed. The first time it works ok. Just put the line:

```
print("selected index = \(self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex ?? -1)")
```

in your viewWillAppear and you will see.

The easiest way to fix your code is to move the logic of PostcodeViewController from viewWillAppear to viewDidAppear.

Comment: Yes that was the fix ! You posted while I was working to the answer for this question ! Thank you so much for your time Alexander !

Answer (score 0):

a simple workaround can be.. store data in a static variable in login class,  you can access it in other classes.

long workaround is,

create a Custom TabBar programmatically, pass data from login viewController to parent CustomTab bar, and pass data to next screen with the help of delegates.

Comment: All my data is fetched in `HomeViewController`. My `LoginViewController` doesn't hold any data.

Comment: i just gave an idea, you know your classes better bro, i just said it as example.. as your gif shows, you are writing hello in a textFiled, there should a button click or an observer on textfield to save data in a static variable.

Comment: The problem seems to be the wrong selectedIndex of TabBarController. I don't know why is going crazy the index. Take a look here please: 
https://recordit.co/BDAIRpzVHU

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to move the code of `PostcodeViewController` from `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidAppear` like this:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        print("Selected index: \(self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex ?? -1)")
        
        if self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex == 1 {
            receivedValueLabel.text = "Value received for Cars: \n" + receivedValueFromHomeScreen
        }

        if self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex == 2 {
            receivedValueLabel.text = "Value received for Bicycles: \n" + receivedValueFromHomeScreen
        }
    }
```

Now everything works perfect !

GIF below:

[image]